# how to generate missing pages in libreoffice writer

Tags: libreoffice

In libreoffice writer I am using different styles for left and right pages. I want to ensure that all headers 1 start on right pages, so in the styles dialog I defined for heading 1 a break of type "page", position "before", with page style "right page". it works, but the problem is: if the previous one is also a right page, there is no left page inserted, damaging the enumeration. i.e: page 21 is right, next page has heading 1 and it got number 23 (good). but there is no page 22.  as I print double-sided it ruins the whole printing.

I expect a blank left page inserted automatically so the enumeration in the footer keeps preserved.

can I do that through settings or it is mandatory to write a macro or something? I don't wanna revisit the whole document and add blank pages by hand each time some edition happens.

Comment: the people at https://ask.libreoffice.org might be more knowledgeable on this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [thread in the OpenOffice.org forums](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=55492): you need to enable the option "Print automatically inserted blank pages" in Writer's Print options (Menu "Tools" -> "Options" -> "LibreOffice Writer" -> "Print"). It's not active by default.

[image]

Notice that this will affect only printing. When exporting the file to PDF, the option to automatically insert blank pages will be ignored. As a workaround, you could use a "PDF Printer" to create a PDF.

Comment: thank you, I checked your suggestion and it worked. for pdf printing, you can select a normal printer and then check "print to file", in that way the PDF will obey the "insert blank pages" option.